# How to upgrade Ubuntu machine from another machine which is already upgraded?

Tags: upgrade

I have two machines which run Ubuntu. I have already upgraded one machine to Ubuntu 16.04. I don't want to download the packages again because it takes hell lot of time. Can I use downloaded packages in first machine to upgrade my second machine?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like apt-cacher-ng on the first machine and then import the packages from apt's cache into apt-cacher-ng using the following instructions:

https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/html/howtos.html#imp

You can find the local archive cache in the following location:

/var/cache/apt/archives

Then just tell the second machine to use apt-cacher-ng on the first machine as an apt proxy, if you set up both machines to use it as a proxy this will also ensure you will only need to download packages once for future updates too saving you and the ubuntu mirrors time and bandwidth.